# Choose best raid for SAN storage

Tags: raid, storage, storage-spaces

guys I have one san storage with 30 8TB hard drive and I want to use it as storage for old video of our site, those videos are for peoples who uploaded them on our site by the way our site is like something like youtube and I stuck with choosing raid I don't have a backup and our company can't afford another san because of that I'm must choose a raid for more capacity and some safety feature and performance I have an idea to use 2 pool with raid 60 with 7 HDD per span so I can tolerate 4 hard failure 2 HDD per span and use 2 HDD for a spare drive. with this idea, I can have 2 72.77 TB per each pool total of 145 TB if each pool downs I have another pool in case of any hard failure or loss of one pool I can have 50% of my data and lost 50% of it. but I going to monitor it with SNMP so if a hard going to fail I can replace it. do you have a better idea? total 30 8TB hard in this san

Comment: Good work picking R6/60, too many people still come to SF talking about 5/50, so thanks for that. You could consider 2 x 13+2 R60 - 6/60 will support such large'ish raid groups.

Comment: actually, I have 2 pools with 14 disks RAID-60 (5+2) assume I have fault to­le­ran­ce of 4 disks per each pool, and I use 2 disks out of 30 disks for spare drive

Comment: How much usable space do you require (not raw, and not what you happen to have)? Is this the only copy of the data?  If you can't afford to lose data, a backup separate from this array is required.

Comment: yep this is the only copy of the data but I can't afford to have another device for backup, by the way, I want to connect 2 hosts to this san and use cluster filesystem and I don't know gfs is better or ocfs2 or other filesystems